# MongoEngine schemata - name error

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have the following schema in a file called model.py

```
from mongoengine import *

class Subject(Document):
    uri = StringField(required=True)
    resources = ListField(ReferenceField(ResourceSubject))

class ResourceSubject(Document):
    subject = ReferenceField(Subject,reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)
    resource = ReferenceField(Resource)

class Resource(EmbeddedDocument):
    uri = StringField()
    title = StringField()
    snippet = StringField()
    image = StringField()
    source = StringField()
    adapter = StringField()
```

For some reason when I try to initialize a Subject, `subj = Subject(uri="hello").save()` I am getting a name error : `NameError: name 'ResourceSubject' is not defined`.

I cant understand the reason, I guess this is related to the framework? I tried separating the classes in individual files and then importing, but I still get the same error. What am I missing ?

The error is thrown on this line: `resources = ListField(ReferenceField(ResourceSubject))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `ResourceSubject` into *quotes*:

```
resources = ListField(ReferenceField('ResourceSubject'))
```

Comment: That was quick... on the tutorial no quotes are used. http://docs.mongoengine.org/tutorial.html

Comment: @Giannis yeah, but since this is a bidirectional reference, both of your models need each other to be defined. In this case providing the model name as a string is the way to go.